# if $f\in D$ show that $f'+p\cdot f\in D$

Tags: real-analysis

Denote by $D$ the set of all real univariate polynomials all of whose roots are real,if $f\in D$,for any real number $p\in R$,show that
$$f'+p\cdot f\in D$$

I konw $$(e^{px}f)'=e^{px}(f'+pf)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the degree of $f$ and $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset\Bbb R$ its roots. Then $f(x)=C\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$. We may assume without loss of generality that $C=1$, and in particular that $f$ has real coefficients.

If $p=0$ the result is a direct consequence of Rolle's theorem.

If $p\ne0$, then $f'+p\,f$ has degree $n$ and real coefficients. By Rolles's theorem, $(e^{px}f)'$ has at least $n-1$ real roots, and since the exponential function does not vanish, $f'+p\,f$ has at least $n-1$ real roots. Since $f'+p\,f$ has real coefficients and complex root come in pairs, all roots of $f'+p\,f$ must be real.